# Is there a way to find variable sized formatting a floating point

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I had tried to solve %4f as a format specifier that gives 4 spaces in right Alignment. However, I need a way to make %4f as %vf where v is a variable number that is given by the user during run time

Comment: With, for example, `int v = 4; printf("%*f", v, myFloat);` Please see [format specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019). Remember though, if the value does not fit the width without loss of signficance, the width is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*`.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float pi = 3.141;

    printf("#%*.3f#\n", 0, pi);
    printf("#%*.3f#\n", 5, pi);
    printf("#%*.3f#\n", 10, pi);
    printf("#%*.3f#\n", 15, pi);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in the following:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe;
#3.141#
#3.141#
#     3.141#
#          3.141#
```